Replicate requests from a primary API endpoint to a lower env for testing purpose
I have a new version of an API which is deployed on UAT environment and wish to test it with the requests executing on the primary API to check functional/non functional aspects of the new api whether its working as expected. Is there any open source tool available to do so? I can fetch the data of the requests from the elastic database.
I had created a script to do so which is not fulfilling the requirement.
